# How to make multiple fragments appear partially in an activity when the corresponding button is pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to make something like this (photos). When a button is pressed (in this app the red button that says "suchen") a fragment in a portion of the main activity screen is shown. And every time I press an other button, the corresponding activity is shown in the same activity.

[image][image]

So when each
button is pressed you can see the corresponding fragment for this button in the portion of the screen where the layout for the fragment is. I did it like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/first_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/second_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/third_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/forth_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Relativelayout
        android:layout_below="@id/first_btn"
        android:id="@+id/first_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment1"
            android:name="com.example.ulrich.kitchentimer.fragments.FirstFragmentActivity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout="@layout/first_fragment_activity" />

    </Relativelayout>

    <Relativelayout
        android:layout_below="@id/first_btn"
        android:id="@+id/second_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment2"
        android:name="com.example.fragments.SecondFragmentActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/second_fragment_activity" />
    </Relativelayout>

    <Relativelayout
        android:layout_below="@id/first_btn"
        android:id="@+id/third_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment3"
        android:name="com.example.fragments.ThirdFragmentActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/third_fragment_activity" />
    </Relativelayout>

    <Relativelayout
        android:layout_below="@id/first_btn"
        android:id="@+id/forth_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment4"
        android:name="com.example.fragments.ForthFragmentActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/forth_fragment_activity" />
    </Relativelayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see in my code I use four buttons and every button opens an other fragment but at the same place on the main activity. So I have four layouts to contain each of the four fragments. I set each layout to be invisible in the XML code and when each button is pressed to open the corresponding fragment I set the layout to be visible in the Java code. So I have four layout containers in the main activity that are hidden and only shown when the corresponding button is pressed.  Is this the right way? Is there a right way?
Thank you in advanced!!!

Comment: From the image, probably that is `ViewPager` with two `fragments`. Try to implement that by customizing `DialogFragment`.

Comment: @Yupi I just want the fragment I'm showing to be a plain view with a back button so I can return to the main screen. What I'm doing is working. The question is: is it right? Is it the right way to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

That's the one way you did to achieve your goal, but that's not the good way. You don't have to make four fragment instead you can have one fragment and replace it when you press the other button. If you want to replace fragments

```
// Create fragment and give it an argument specifying the article it should show
ArticleFragment newFragment = new ArticleFragment();  
Bundle args = new Bundle();  
args.putInt(ArticleFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);  
newFragment.setArguments(args);

FragmentTransaction transaction = 
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);  
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

**Note:** When you remove or replace a fragment and add the transaction to the back stack, the fragment that is removed is stopped (not destroyed). If the user navigates back to restore the fragment, it restarts. If you do not add the transaction to the back stack, then the fragment is destroyed when removed or replaced. To allow the user to navigate backward through the fragment transactions, you must call **addToBackStack()** before you commit the **FragmentTransaction**.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So the app that I'm showing in the pics, is using the way you are showing? The"problem" with coding is that there is a hundred possible ways to do something, but not all of them are right! Thanks again. I will try it this way ☺

Comment: Your welcome. Only making app is not sufficient, how efficiently you code your app is matters. So, good luck for this.